# Ограничения IIS на Windows server Essentials 2016

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016

Привет! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то ограничения для IIS в редакции Windows server Essentials 2016? Например для редакции Windows 10 Pro MS поставила ограничение на пул приложений IIS из 10 параллельных подключений.